# Sax Implementation vs specification

Tags: java, sax

What is the diference between use SAXParser from Java packages(specification) and implementations like ones in this website [SaxParsers](http://www.edankert.com/jaxpimplementations.html#SAXParserFactory)

Comment: Some are newer, faster and/or better maintained than others. I believe that Xerces is the most commonly used.

Comment: Ya,but if they use sax parser from java packages,why they need to implement new one?

Comment: Like I said, an existing one might have some bugs and now in your control to fix, or be slower, or you might have a libraries which attempts to be the best of all the others, or have a less restrictive license.